# How to import or load cryptojs in groovy scripting?

Tags: groovy

I am doing groovy scripting in ReadyAPI tool for API automation, i need to do 'CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse("secretkey") .
But it says 'CryptoJs' not defined. Can any one help me on this?
I have already added 'crypto-js-3.1.9-1' jar file in readyapi bin/ext folder.

Answer (score 1):

CryptoJS (from https://www.webjars.org/ I guess) is a `JavaScript` library - not `Groovy`.

You can't execute JavaScript code directly in groovy.

There are crypting algorithms supported natively in java/groovy. Just search by `algorithm name` + `java`.

I know that readyapi supports `rhino javascript` as scripting language, but i'm not sure it's possible to import external javascript libraries..